# How to create count down timer

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to display decreasing order count down timer from `20 sec` till `00 sec`

If he/she fail to enter password within the given 20 sec
then exit with message *your time is over*

**Output :**

```
you have 20 sec to enter password :
you have 15 sec to enter password :
you have 10 sec to enter password :
you have 00 sec to enter password :
```

**Partial working code which display message**

```
read -t 20 -p 'Enter your password : ' 
status=$?   
if [ $status -eq 142 ]
then
    echo "your time is over"
fi
```

Comment: Which shell, specifically? In bash, you can use the `read` builtin's `-t` option to set a timeout

Comment: The `read` builtin and its `-t` (timeout) options are documented in `man bash`.

Comment: ... `read -t 20 -p 'Enter your password : ' password`

Comment: `nothing happens as expected` does not describe what actually happens ... it is like describing rainfall by saying `we did not get 5 cm of rain yesterday`

Comment: The problem here is that you want to update the output (either refresh the existing line or writing a new one) and you would disturb the user trying to provide the input.

Comment: @thanasisp Not if writing the prompt and reading the input is done by two separate processes or subshells running concurrently.

Comment: What I think is something like `(for (()); do ...done)&` to print the counter and `read ...` to get the input, and probably `tput` the cursor to the correct position, but I am not sure if this again will not disturb the user trying to type the input (or for any race conditions). Maybe there are solutions for this or like this, but some testing is needed.

Comment: @thanasisp  what you said is right the count down timer should get change constantly till it reaches the end value , need to refresh existing count down timer value

Comment: @codeholic24 check my final edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until someone comes up with a nicer solution:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

tmout=20

(
        while [[ $tmout -gt 0 ]]; do
                printf '\rPlease respond within %02d seconds: ' "$tmout" >&2
                sleep 1
                tmout=$(( tmout - 1 ))
        done
) & prompt_pid=$!

read -s -t "$tmout"
read_ok=$?
echo ''

if [[ $read_ok -eq 0 ]]; then
        kill "$prompt_pid"
        printf 'You responded with "%s"\n' "$REPLY"
else
        echo 'You did not respond in time'
fi
```

This starts a background job that updates a prompt once a second for `$tmout` seconds or until killed.  The prompt text is preceded by `\r`, a carriage return.  Outputting `\r` with `printf` moves the cursor back to the start of the line, which means that the rest of the string will overwrite whatever text was previously outputted, giving the impression of a ticking counter. I'm deliberately using a zero-filled two-digit integer for the counter, so that the text string outputted by `printf` is always the same length (at least for values of `$tmout` less than 100).

The foreground job then waits `$tmout` seconds for input from the user using `read` with a timeout.  I'm using `-s` with `read` here as we're reading a password (this also means that what's being typed won't be shown and won't be messed up by the outputted prompt).

Once `read` returns, we make sure to kill the prompt loop if it's still running and then print a message depending on how `read` terminated.

Comment: Mine is working as the output wanted  on the question ; why it should be dismissed !!!

Comment: @RedaSalih Sorry to interrupt but the Input line should get updated in decreasing order , it should be like animation and that is not getting from your code , if you can make it like animation it will be useful for all

Comment: @RedaSalih The output is easily modifiable. The issue with your code, which I already mentioned in a comment to your answer, is that you don't actually give the user 20 seconds to answer. You give them 5 seconds, four times (actually five times).

Comment: @Kusalananda May be the question need to be modified a little , it should be like how to create animation count down timer

Comment: @AdminBee So it seems. Interesting. It must be that way since the line entered to an earlier `read` was never actually submitted, and therefor still valid input for the next `read`.  That's rather neat, and would, if cleaned up a bit, get rid of the need for a background process.

Comment: @RedaSalih See above comments. You're on to something there. You just need to sort out the output of the prompt, and probably use `read -s` too.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that I deleted my comment in a confused moment.

Comment: I have made  my last edit so it will be a global solution with the wanted output :). For the first answer i just interpreted the question as it is. Thanks

Comment: With the last edit the prompt will be exactly as it was asked for :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet ; When reaching 00 seconds it will wait more 5s you can edit it with a condition because i don't know if this is the behaviour wanted :

```
#!/bin/bash
c1=5
c2=4
count=20
status=''
while [[ "$count" != 0 ]]   
    do
        count="$(expr $c1 \* $c2)"
        c2="$(expr $c2 \- 1)"
        read -t 5 -p  "You have $count sec to enter your password : "$'\n'
        status=$?
        if [ "$status" -ne 142 ] ; then
          break
        fi

done
if [ "$status" -eq 142 ]
then
    echo "Your time is over"
    
else 
   echo "Success"
fi
```

**###EDIT###**

*OUTPUT 1 :*

```
[root@host~]# ./lol.sh
You have 20 sec to enter your password :
You have 15 sec to enter your password :
You have 10 sec to enter your password :
You have 5 sec to enter your password :
You have 0 sec to enter your password :
Your time is over
```

*OUTPUT 2 :*

```
[root@host~]# ./lol.sh
You have 20 sec to enter your password :
LOL
Success
[root@host~]#
```

**## EDIT 2  MORE GLOBAL SOLUTION as suggested in the comments ## :**

With this one the counter is exactly 20seconds ; you can change **tmt** & **wait_sec** constants at your convenience.

```
#!/bin/bash
##CALCULATTION :
##TIMEOUT=WAIT_SECONDS * NB_ITERATIONS 
##TIMEOUT modulo WAIT_SECONDS should  equal to 0 to get a fixed iterations number
# 20  =   5 * 4 
wait_sec=5
tmt=20
modulo_ok=1
fpr=1
count="$tmt"
# Modulo Test
if [[ "$(($tmt % $wait_sec))" -eq 0 ]]; then
    nb_iters="$(expr $tmt \/ $wait_sec)"
    modulo_ok=0
fi
if [[ "modulo_ok" -eq 0 ]]; then
    (while [[ "$count" != 0 ]] && [[ "$fpr" -gt 0 ]]
        do
            count="$(expr $wait_sec \* $nb_iters)"
            nb_iters="$(expr $nb_iters \- 1)"
            echo "You have $count sec to enter your password :" 
            ps -p "$pid" &> /dev/null 
            sleep $wait_sec
    done
    ) &  fpr=$?  
    bpr=$!
    read -t "$tmt" -s pass
    kill $bpr > /dev/null 2>&1 
    if [[ -z  "$pass" ]]
    then
        echo "Your time is over"
    else 
       echo "Success"
       echo "Your password is : $pass"
    fi 
else 
    echo 'Timeout modulo Wait seconds should be equal to 0'
fi
```

*OUTPUT 3 :*  CASE  -> Password set during the tmt interval

```
[root@host~]# ./lol2.sh
You have 20 sec to enter your password :
You have 15 sec to enter your password :
Success
Your password is : Reda
```

*OUTPUT 4 :* CASE  -> Timeout

```
[root@host~]# ./lol2.sh
You have 20 sec to enter your password :
You have 15 sec to enter your password :
You have 10 sec to enter your password :
You have 5 sec to enter your password :
Your time is over
```

*OUTPUT 5 :* CASE  -> tmt % wait_sec is different from 0

```
[root@host~]# ./lol2.sh
Timeout modulo Wait seconds should be equal to 0
```

Comment: I have made an edit to add break :) I prefer expr lol

Comment: @Kusalananda The code is showing abnormal behaviour this is what i am getting : `You have 20 sec to enter your password : You have 15 sec to enter your password : You have 10 sec to enter your password : You have 5 sec to enter your password :` that to in horizontal format

Comment: I have made an edit to print new line :)

Comment: @RedaSalih Not working can you test on your local the code

Comment: Yes i have tested it and i have put appended the OUTPUT to the answer.

Comment: @RedaSalih can you check the output of Kusalananda this output is needed which yours is not getting , Only the one line should get constantly get updated

Comment: Yes i have just checked but it's different from needed output on the question :) Mine is identical just having new line \n instead. No upvote !!!!